# Windows Forms: Pass clicks through a partially transparent always-on-top window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, transparent

I am designing a window that is always on screen and around 20% opaque. It is designed to be a sort of status window, so it is always on top, but I want people to be able to click through the window to any other application below. Here's the opaque window sitting on top of this SO post as I type right now:

[image: Example]

See that grey bar? It would prevent me from typing in the tags box at the moment.

Comment: Not possible with winforms.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up that answer? I find that hard to believe...

Comment: Believe it.  My "evidence" is over a decade of experience using win forms.

Comment: @rory.ap I think the posted answer is what the OP is looking for. Am I missing some part of the question? It's working on Windows 7.

Comment: I stand corrected.  That's pretty cool!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can make a window, click-through by adding [`WS_EX_LAYERED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) styles to its extended styles. Also to make it always on top set its [`TopMost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to `true` and to make it semi-transparent use suitable [`Opacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) value:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = 0.5;
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
    const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var style = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(this.Handle,GWL_EXSTYLE , style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

**Sample Result**

[image]

Comment: You could just override CreateParams and set the ExStyle instead using P/Invoke.

Comment: I tried this solution but when I click through the window  happens nothing

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow Click will pass to the background window.

Comment: I use ubuntu with mono seems that this not working...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61000080/create-windows-transparent-without-interaction-with-mouse-and-keyboard-like-peek

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow It's WinForms (.NET) on Windows not mono on Linux.

Comment: Ya but mono support completely windows form 2.0, this work in part, for example, like as the posted gif but the click non work....

Comment: @BruceStackOverFlow The part which is not working is in fact the Windows API part :)