# Fade WS_EX_LAYERED form

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I have a form which I make click-through using the following function calls:

```cs
SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)(GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED ^ WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 0xFF, LWA_ALPHA);
```

This works fine, however when I try to fade that window using the `System.Windows.Forms.Form.Opacity` property I get the following exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is not valid
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Opacity(Double value)
```

How can I achieve both things at the same time?

Comment: Looks like 3rd parameter should be 0x80.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetLayeredWindowAttributes.html

Comment: @jdweng Setting the third parameter to `0x7F` sadly didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856049/3110834)?

Comment: The pinvoke code confuzzles Winforms, it doesn't know that you created a layered window.  You just don't need it at all, simply setting the Opacity property is enough to get Winforms to set the exstyle and make that SetLayeredWindowAttributes() call.  If this is an attempt to eliminate flicker then be sure to not set Opacity to 1 (aka 100 in the Properties window), change it between 0 and 0.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works on a windows form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication30
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern System.UInt32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, int crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);



        public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        public const uint WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
        public const uint LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
        public const uint LWA_COLORKEY = 0x1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            IntPtr Handle = this.Handle;
            UInt32 windowLong = GetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong32(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, (uint)(windowLong ^ WS_EX_LAYERED));
            SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Handle, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
        }
    }
}
```