# Pass clicks to parent views

Tags: c#, uwp, onclick, opacity, caliburn.micro

I have a TextBlock on top of other views with low opacity, How ever this is eating the click events (as well as mouse hovering events) and does not let underneath views to recieve click events.

How do I avoid this in UWP with or without caliburn micro?

---

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855720/windows-forms-pass-clicks-through-a-partially-transparent-always-on-top-window) but this is for winforms, Also I only want this effect for a single view not entire window.

---

I have tried `PointerEntered`, `Tapped`, `Holding` events to set their handled parameter to true or false but none of that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to set `IsHitTestVisible` to false :|